# Run shell command from Ansible

Tags: shell, ansible

I have a shell script which just changes directory (here directory path is given).

shell file

```bash
#!/bin/bash
p="dir/file/create"
cd "$p"
exec bash
```

Ansible playbook

```yaml
---
 - hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: true
   become: true
   become_user: oracle
   become_flags: 'content-ansible'
   tasks:
   - name: changing dir now..
     command: sh /dir/file/create/vars.sh
```

I want to run a shell script to change directory path in ANSIBLE and run subsequent shell file(#2) in the directory (again shell script).

Ansible playbook completes but I never am able to get into a directory and execute the shell script(#2).

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use the [`chdir`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html#parameters) parameter?

> **`chdir`**: cd into this directory before running the command

From the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html#shell-module):

```yaml
- name: Change the working directory to somedir/ before executing the command.
  command: somescript.sh
  args:
    chdir: somedir/
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script you should enter complete PATH:

```
#!/bin/bash
p="/dir/file/create"
cd "$p"
```

Don't use sh in front of COMMAND module:

```
   - name: changing dir now..
     command: /dir/file/create/vars.sh
```

but 'shell' module is better than 'command' module for your issue.

Answer (score -2):

I tried this option and it seems fine for me:

```
pre_tasks:
 - include_vars: vars.yml
tasks:
 - name: Do task...
   shell: cd "{{v_dir}}" && sh shell2.sh
```

Comment: The `chdir` parameter is also available for the shell module.

Comment: Kind of a redundant hack. Technically it may work, but its not too far off from writing everything into a bash script. Ansible has the tools you need to complete this, as @kaliko has pointed out.